# Cannot include user-agent into my headers

Tags: c#, post, http-headers

I'm currently trying to send a post request with a user agent however I get errors every time I try to use a user agent. Please may someone help?

I've already tried:

```
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "{My user agent}");
```

I get this error when I try to use the code above:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent` instead of a string "User-Agent". That'll fix it.

Comment: `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "{My user agent}");`